# Não consigo fazer com que a tag p com footer desça até o final da tela utilizando % com React js

Tags: react

**

- App.js

**
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Contact from "./components/pages/Contact";
import Company from "./components/pages/Company";
import NewProject from "./components/pages/NewProject";

import Container from "./components/layout/Container";

function App() {
return (



Home
Contato
Empresa
Novo Projeto

```
    <Switch>
      <Container customClass="min-height">
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/company">
          <Company />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact">
          <Contact />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/newproject">
          <NewProject />
        </Route>
      </Container>
    </Switch>

    <p>Footer</p>
  </Router>
</div>
```

);
}

export default App;

**

- Container.js

**
import styles from "./Container.module.css";

function Container(props) {
return (
<div className={`${styles.container} ${styles[props.customClass]}`}>
{props.children}

);
}

export default Container;

**

- Index.css

**

- {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }

html,body,#root {
min-height: 100%;
background: #efefef;
}

**

- Container.module.css

**
.container {
width: 1200px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: 0 auto;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.min-height {
min-height: 100%; /* ajuste o valor conforme necessário */

}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.